# Creating a new variable based on the orders of existing variables using R

Tags: r, variables, time-series

Hoping to create the new variable X based on three existing variables: "SubID" "Day" and "Time". I used to have three sorting functions in excel to do this manually: first sort by the "SubID," and then sort by the "Day," and lastly sort by "Time." X should be from 1 to the largest number of rows for each SubID, based on the order of Day and Time.

SubID: assigned subject number

Day: each subject's day number (1,2,3...21)

Time: 1, 2, 3

X: the number of rows marked as the same SubID

```
SubID Day  Time   X    
 1    1     1     1
 1    1     2     2
 1    1     3     3
 1    2     1     4
 1    2     2     5
 2    1     1     1
 2    1     2     2
 2    1     3     3
 2    2     3     6
 2    2     2     5
 2    2     1     4
```

I have been doing this manually in excel and I am sure there must be a smarter way to do it in R, but I am new to R and don't know how. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be with data.table package. You will have to install it in case you haven't already. I have commented the command.

```
# install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
```

we can generate your data in the following way.

```
df <- data.frame(SubId=sample(1:2,10,replace=TRUE),
                 Day=sample(1:2,10,replace=TRUE),
                     Time=sample(1:2,10,replace=TRUE))
```

Then convert the data.frame into data.table.

```
setDT(df)
##> df
##     SubId Day Time
##  1:     1   2    1
##  2:     1   1    1
##  3:     1   1    2
##  4:     2   2    1
##  5:     2   1    1
##  6:     1   2    2
##  7:     1   2    1
##  8:     1   2    2
##  9:     2   1    1
## 10:     2   1    2
```

Finally we can order my SubId, Day ,Time. As the table is ordered as we wanted, we just have to number the rows from 1 to the number of observations in each SubId.

```
df[order(SubId,Day,Time),X:=1:.N,SubId]


##> df
##    SubId Day Time X
## 1:     1   2    1 3
## 2:     1   1    1 1
## 3:     1   1    2 2
## 4:     2   2    1 4
## 5:     2   1    1 1
## 6:     1   2    2 5
## 7:     1   2    1 4
## 8:     1   2    2 6
## 9:     2   1    1 2
## 10:    2   1    2 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanations! They are very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(SubID) %>% 
  mutate(X1 = row_number(as.numeric(paste0(Day, Time))))
# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   SubID [2]
#   SubID   Day  Time     X    X1
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2     1     1     2     2     2
# 3     1     1     3     3     3
# 4     1     2     1     4     4
# 5     1     2     2     5     5
# 6     2     1     1     1     1
# 7     2     1     2     2     2
# 8     2     1     3     3     3
# 9     2     2     3     6     6
#10     2     2     2     5     5
#11     2     2     1     4     4
```

---

Or using `order`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(SubID) %>% 
  mutate(X1 = order(Day, Time))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, X1 := order(Day, Time), by = SubID]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SubID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
Time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), X = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, 
   -11L))
```

Comment: The codes ran, but when I went to check the new variable X1, R said it is "null." Meaning I haven't recreated the variable yet? Sorry for this stupid question, I am new to R. The codes I used are: data2 %>% 
        group_by(SubID) %>% 
        mutate(X1 = order(Day, Time))

data2$X1

Comment: @Susan You need to assign it to data i.e. `data2 <- data2 %>% group_by(SubID) %>% mutate(X1 = order(Day, Time))`